# Pages: can I style space before a set of characters?

Tags: pages, formatting, space

I wish to add space before a span of characters:

---

[image]

---

As an afterthought, I may realize this isn't a job for Character Styles, since those
operate on single characters, not spans/groups of characters.

Neither does it look to be a job for Paragraph Styles, since those
operate on blocks of text (paragraphs); not inline blocks.

Comment: I'd suggest using the space bar.

Comment: This is the option I wanted to avoid, since the document may be handled by others than me and they most likely won't understand that they should type "09 40" instead of "0940". Even more importantly, the *REAL* reason I want to avoid such styling is because adding a space between "09" and "40", in this case, would extend the dark gray background …whereas I want the light gray to be the one extended. (I want the same distance on Time - Minutes' left side to be the exact same as on the right side, from the "0" to the edge of the light gray background, if I'm making any sense).

Comment: This still wouldn't fix the first reason, but couldn't you have the space styled as "Time - Minutes" rather than "Time -Hours"?

Comment: @Timothy re: adding a space and styling it with "Time - Minutes". That's a considerable idea in terms of achieving the look I'm after (thanks for pointing it out!). Although I'm a bit sceptical about the fact that typing "09 ␣ ␣ 40" (using *two* spaces between) is required to achieve the effect, and adding salt to injury, having the person editing person remember to switch the appropriate style (to "Time - Minutes") for the added space. :(

Comment: I don't think two spaces are required... if you type one space, select it, and style it, does that not do the trick?

Comment: But yes, I see what you mean.